# Get Message ID in response - SendGrid API v3

Tags: php, sendgrid

I am getting this response when I submit an email, as I am working on the `API of SendGrid` I need to grab the stats of each mail i sent.. for that purpose I want the `Message-ID` in response so I could save that in db.. I have looked over the docs but unable to make any progress.. Thanks in Advance

P.S : does X-Message-Id could help in this ? if yes than how.. 
below is the url of doc from where we can retrive mails

https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/email-activity/filter-all-messages

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
    [1] => Server: nginx
    [2] => Date: Tue, 27 Nov 2018 15:59:04 GMT
    [3] => Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
    [4] => Content-Length: 0
    [5] => Connection: keep-alive
    [6] => X-Message-Id: -ekBjiGXRNi7l5OdjBRcRA
    [7] => Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://sendgrid.api-docs.io
    [8] => Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
    [9] => Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl
    [10] => Access-Control-Max-Age: 600
    [11] => X-No-CORS-Reason: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html
    [12] => 
    [13] => 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

"The SendGrid assigned Message ID is different than an X-Message-ID given in response headers when sending via API. While this ID is contained in the SendGrid assigned Message ID, the X-Message-ID is specific to the API request prior to messages being broken up individually in SendGrid email servers and then assigned the SendGrid Message ID. The SendGrid Message ID accounts not only for the original request but also server data and the specific identification between a unique message and recipient."

https://docs.sendgrid.com/glossary/message-id